# ScrollingTextView not working when clock is visible

Tags: android

I have a TextView in my application which shows the current time, i implemented it like this

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();


private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{

public void run() 
{
   batteryLevel();
     if(clock_on == true) {


         Handler clockUpdate = new Handler(); 
         clockUpdate.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
              public void run() {
                  executeClock();
              } 
         }, 500);



     }
     handler.post(this);






}

public void executeClock() {



    TextView timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
    String timeFormat24 = "%1$tH:%1$tM";   
 //   String timeFormat12 = "%1$tI:%1$tM";
    String showTime=String.format(timeFormat24,cal);
    timeTv.setText(showTime);


}
```

In my app i have a ScrollingTextView aswell, ScrollingtextView.java

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    if(focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    if(focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}


@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}
```

}

```
<com.doublep.example.ScrollingTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_lcd_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#f82424"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
```

The ScrollingTextView doesn't work if the clock TextView is visible, when i make the visibility of the clock GONE then the ScrollingTextView works perfectly

Why is this happening?
How can i fix it?

EDIT: if i delay the clock the ScrollingTextView starts working, but as soon as the clock TextView gets set to the current time,  the ScrollingTextView stops working

UPDATE: after a bit of testing i noticed that the ScrollingTextView is working, but every time the executeClock() method runs, the ScrollingTextView animation gets reset and starts once again

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your clock textview and scrolltextview in the same viewgroup?? so for example are they all child views of the same linear or relative layout?? Try to separate them and make them child of different viewgroups. That worked for me once and may work for you too

Comment: The clock is in the main layout>central>central_console    
And the ScrollText is in main layout>lcd>lcd_screen